# Web Setup Project Prerequisites CLR Types

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, prerequisites

I am trying to create a Web Setup Project using [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9).

```
The web application is being developed using MVC5 and Entity Framework.
```

My application can work with SQL Server 2012 also. But, when I tried to set prerequisites it shows me CLR Types only for SQL Server 2014.
Did I missed something? Please help...
What should I do? Do I need to add both as in screen below?

- CLR Types for SQL Server 2014 (x64)
- CLR Types for SQL Server 2014 (x86)

[image]

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580

Comment: @HansPassant I don't want to download.. All I want is to set Prerequisites while creation of setup file and I have confusion whether it will work without CLR Types or not after installation?